# Operator groups

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In $H := L^2(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)$ Hilbert-space, the following two, one-variable operator groups are given:

$$(U_s f)(x):=f(x-s)$$
$$(V_s f)(x):=e^{is x} f(x)$$

$f \in H, s \in \mathbb{R}$.

**a,** Prove, that for every $s \in \mathbb{R}, U_s, V_s$ are unitary opeartors!

**b,** Prove, that for every $t,s \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$U_t U_s= U_{t+s}, V_t V_s= V_{t+s}$$

**c,** What is the value of $[U_t,V_s]=U_t V_s - V_s U_t$ commutator?

For point $b,$ I had some ideas.

$U_t U_s = U_{t+s}$ is trivial, because we substract $t+s$ from $x$, if we use the two operators. Same goes for the other case.

I don't really have idea how to do the rest, any hint appreciated.

Comment: For a) try to find the adjoint of $U_s$. Notice that $U_sU_{-s}=U_0=Id$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) We have that $U_sU_{-s}=Id=U_{-s}U_s$ and $$<U_sf,g>=\int_{\mathbb{R}} U_sf(x)\overline{g(x)}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}  f(x-s)\overline{g(x)}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\overline{g(x+s)}\mathrm{d}x=<f,U_{-s}g>.$$ Hence $U_s^*=U_{-s}$. By the first identity $U_s$ is unitary. Try $V_s$ yourself.

c) We have that $$(U_tV_sf-V_sU_tf)(x)= U_t(V_sf)(x)-V_s(U_tf)(x)=(V_sf)(x-t)-e^{isx}U_tf(x)=e^{is(x-t)}f(x-t)-e^{isx}f(x-t)=e^{isx}(e^{-ist}-1)f(x-t).$$

Hence $[U_t,V_s]=(e^{-ist}-1)V_sU_t$.

Comment: You dropped the 'i' in the exponent at the very end, both at the end of the last display equation, and also in the final statement of the commutator. And, should you have $(e^{-ist}-1)$ instead?

Comment: Yes, fixed that. Thank you.